# How to solve the import cycle using an interface in Golang?

Tags: go, import, interface, cycle

I have encountered an import cycle problem @icza and I am trying to use the interface to solve this but after going through some resources, I still didn't understand properly and it is giving me an error that

**Error**

`runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit runtime: sp=0xc020160360 stack=[0xc020160000, 0xc040160000] fatal error: stack overflow`

**file1.go**

```
package dir1

type Functions interface {
    Second(string) string
}

func First(f Functions, message string) string {
    importFile2 := f.Second("second file")
    return "Welcome to " + message + " and message from file 2: " + importFile2
}
```

**file2.go**

```
package dir2

import "github.com/ibilalkayy/app/dir1"

type SecondT struct{}

func (SecondT) Second(message string) string {
    importFile1 := dir1.First(SecondT{}, "first file")
    return "Welcome to " + message + " and message from file 1: " + importFile1
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ibilalkayy/app/dir1"
    "github.com/ibilalkayy/app/dir2"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
    first := dir1.First(dir2.SecondT{}, "first file")
    fmt.Println(first)
}
```

Comment: Your code as written above won't compile.  But you posted in a comment below the answer given that you are getting a stack overflow, which indicates that the code above is _not_ your current code.  Can you please edit your question to show the current state of your code?

Comment: Hey @SandyCash, sorry for the late response. I have update the code. These are the changes that Burak suggested me.

Comment: First and Second call each other, leading to infinite recursion. We cannot really suggest a solution other than "don't do that" because this is a contrived example and it's entirely unclear what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Peter I have redis and mysql files and that is causing the import cycle problem? I gave this code so that I can solve it.

Comment: Your code, as written, does not present an import cycle problem _per se_.  Redis and mysql have nothing to do with your current issue.   Your code creates an infinitely deep call stack, bounded only by the memory available to the process.  I'm with @Peter - this is a pretty fundamental issue that has nothing to do with whatever your actual use case is.